# how not to announce static and button widgets collectively in flutter

Tags: flutter, accessibility, semantics

I'm using a card which contained a lot of static and dynamic buttons . I WANT  how to not announce all these information collectively by the screen reader. Expected behaviour only announced one element as i swipe right of left

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it's not easy to answer this. If you tab to one card, all the information inside that card is potential announced. To avoid this you can give the card container an aria label. The label will then be read instead of the content inside the container.